# Server-Side Swift 3: How to access the shell environment?

Tags: swift, shell, unix, swift3

I'm taking a script that I hacked together in Ruby (in mere moments ;)) as a baseline exploration of how Swift works as a scripting language. I'm using Swift 3.0 on Linux using core libraries only (no deps for a script like this, I figure).

I've discovered [CommandLine](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/commandline). That gave me my `ARGV` and `ARGC` data. I can use those to parse the command line. While I'd like for there to be a long opts parser library, I can make do on my own (although recommendations appreciated).

The other vital data in scripts come from the `env`. I'm trying to figure out how to access those. I would have thought `CommandLine` would have made those accessible, but I've not yet found it.

Looking at the [Swift API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift), I've not found a good candidate. Is there somewhere else I should be looking? I'm really excited about a Swift programming community emerging (that's not bound to the little hardware set in my pocket) and want to start carrying the banner for these scripts!

Comment: The linked-to Q&A should answer your question, otherwise let me know and I'll reopen this one.

Comment: Confirmed: That's a fix.